# vscode creats a Conda enviroment in current workspace doesn't response

Tags: visual-studio-code, conda, pylance

I connect another host with vscode-ssh, and installed neccesary extension on it.

I want to let vscode pylance extension recognizing the installed packages in my conda env base by selecting python interpreter or selecting python environment.

But I failed because selecting python interpreter or selecting python environment currently doesn't work in my vscode, because it doesn't response any change after I click the option I want to select but dropdown disappear.

**Step to reproduce**:

Firstly, I opened my vscode and the conda env `base` auto-activated while launching vscode terminal.
[image]
Secondly, I `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P` and click `Python: Create Environment...`
[image]
Thirdly, I selected `Conda` when select an environment type
[image]
Then the dropdown disappear without any response.

It should excute something and detect my conda env and sync the package to pylance extension so that I can click into the source code of each modules that I imported in my code.

Additional information:

When I click on the python icon here in the right-button bars in my vscode
[image]
It only shows the dropdown like this
[image]
Not the select python interpreter